# NodeJS POST keeps pending

Tags: node.js, post, callback, mongoose, callstack

I am posting a json string with jQuery to my NodeJS backend, and having issues with handeling post data in my backend. It looks like the backend is blocking somewhere, but I can't find where. Therefore, my POSTS keep the status pending, and sometimes it return OK with a 200.

My code below loops with async.forEach retValTravelInsurerList, which is an array of 23 insurers. I have a nested async.forEach which set a constructor with values, and executes a query in filterTravelInsurerCoverage. This means that 23 queries are executed via Mongoose (MongoDB) database.

I only need the items in retValTravelInsurerList if they are found in the filterTravelInsurerCoverage array, and I will populate a new array (retValTravelInsurerAndCoverageList) where all the needed items are stored.

There is no problem with the POST status in case the travelinsurercoverage has coverages for all the item in retValTravelInsurerList => let's say 23.

But if the resulting array (retValTravelInsurerAndCoverageList) length is smaller then (travelinsurercoverage) length, then POST issues occur, and if I post a couple of times to the server, the status keeps 'PENDING' in Chrome's javascript console.

It looks to me that there are still items in the NodeJS call stack, which are blocking future POSTS, even when return callback(); is called.

Does someone know how to solve this problem?

Btw: I work with the async library, and after return callback(); is called, res.send(JSON.stringify(retValTravelInsurerAndCoverageList)); is called.

```
function(callback) {
  var count = 0;
  async.forEach(retValTravelInsurerList, function(item, callback1) {

    count++;

    travelinsurercoverageMdl.constructorTravelInsurerCoverage('', item._id, item.familytype,'','',this.wintersport,'',this.adventuresport, this.accidents,'','','','',this.motoristaid,'','','');
    travelinsurercoverageMdl.filterTravelInsurerCoverage(function(travelinsurercoverage, callback2){

      count--;

      async.forEach(travelinsurercoverage, function(item2, callback3) {

        retValTravelInsurerAndCoverageList.push({

          //I have shorted the list below, to 
          //get a better overview of the code
          //travel_insurer
          _id: item._id,
          name: item.name

          //travel_insurercoverage                        
          adventuresport: item2.adventuresport,
          accidents: item2.accidents,
          cashcoverageextraamount: item2.cashcoverageextraamount

          //extra fields
          familytype: item.familytype
        });

        if(count == 0) {
          return callback(); //if count is subtracted completely, then the list is finished and can be calledback to the res.send function.
        }
      }, callback1); //callback to retValTravelInsurerList to get the next item in the array.
    });
  });
}],
function(err) {
  if(err){
    return (err);
  } else {
    res.send(JSON.stringify(retValTravelInsurerAndCoverageList));
  }
});
```

Below is the function filterTravelInsurerCoverage stated, which is called by the inner async.forEach. The dynamic where and the array are shorted...

```
   async.series([

    function(callback)
    {
        //define the model
        var travelinsurercoverageModel = conn.model('travel_insurercoverages', schema);

        //define the query
        var query = travelinsurercoverageModel.find();

        //build dynamic where
        if(utilnull.isItemNullValue(locals._cancellation3000))
        { query.where({'Cancellation3000': {'$gte' : 0}}); }
        if(utilnull.isItemNullValue(locals._motoristaid))
        { query.where({'MotoristAid': {'$gte' : 0}}); }
        if(utilnull.isItemNullValue(locals._businesstravel))
        { query.where({'BusinessTravel': {'$gte' : 0}}); }
        if(utilnull.isItemNullValue(locals._extendedtravelperiod))
        { query.where({'ExtendedTravelPeriod': {'$gte' : 0}}); }
        if(utilnull.isItemNullValue(locals._extendedtravelprice))
        { query.where({'ExtendedTravelPrice': {'$gte' : 0}}); }

        //execute query
        query.exec(function (err, reis) {
            if (err) return callback(err);

            reis.forEach(function(item) {

                retVal.push({
                    _id: item.id,
                    insuranceidref: item.InsuranceIDREF,
                    familytype: item.FamilyType,
                    basepriceeurope: item.BasePriceEurope,
                    businesstravel: item.BusinessTravel,
                    extendedtravelperiod: item.ExtendedTravelPeriod,
                    extendedtravelprice: item.ExtendedTravelPrice
                });
            });
            callback();
        })
    }
    ],
    function(err)
    {
        if(err){
            return err;
        }
        else {
            callback(retVal);
        }
    }
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to come with your callback handling.

The way async.forEach is meant to be use is the following:

```
async.forEach(array, function(item, next) {
  // do stuff with item, which comes from the array
  next();
  // ALWAYS invoke next(). If you have an error and need to stop the processing, pass an error argument
}, function(err) {
  // end callback, invoked when all item where processed, of when an error is reported
});
```

`forEach` will process your stuff in parallel. If you need to stop them, call `next` with an error, and your end callback will be invoked while other unprocessed item won't be fired.

You should never break this workflow by using `return`, throwing errors or invoking another callback from parent scopes.

**--- EDIT --**

For example, you could have something like this:

```
function(callback) {

  async.forEach(retValTravelInsurerList, function(item, next1) {

    travelinsurercoverageMdl.constructorTravelInsurerCoverage('', item._id, item.familytype,'','',this.wintersport,'',this.adventuresport, this.accidents,'','','','',this.motoristaid,'','','');

    // here is an asynchronous processing: next1 will be invoked when it ends
    travelinsurercoverageMdl.filterTravelInsurerCoverage(function(travelinsurercoverage, callback2){

    async.forEach(travelinsurercoverage, function(item2, next2) {

      retValTravelInsurerAndCoverageList.push({

        //I have shorted the list below, to 
        //get a better overview of the code
        //travel_insurer
        _id: item._id,
        name: item.name

        //travel_insurercoverage                        
        adventuresport: item2.adventuresport,
        accidents: item2.accidents,
        cashcoverageextraamount: item2.cashcoverageextraamount

        //extra fields
        familytype: item.familytype
      });
      // item2 processing is finished: let nested async.forEach knows about it
      next2();
    }, next1); // when all item2 in travelinsurercoverage are processed, let first async.forEach knows about it
  }, callback); // when all item in retValTravelInsurerList are processed, your overall processing is ok.
```

Comment: You probably don't know how thankful I am! It works great now :)